# How to bind ItemsSource to multiple collections?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a few sources that expose an `ObservableCollection<MyData>` property. Now I want to bind `ListBox.ItemsSource` to all of them and support `CollectionChanged` notifications, sorting and filtering. How to do that? `CompositeCollection` doesn't support filtering.

Comment: Do you mean you want to bind to all of the sources at once and receive updates from them all (MultiBinding - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) or you want to bind to multiple sources and receive updates from the first that responds (PriorityBinding - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx)

Comment: I want to display flattened list from all collections and receive changes from all of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288/wpf-sorting-a-composite-collection

Answer (score 0):

You can use CompositeCollection  and CollectionViewSource together..  use CompositeCollection  to combine all collections and later create a collection view source from that CompositeCollection. You can use filter properties in CollectionViewSource

Look Here for Sample

[How to handle a CompositeCollection with CollectionView features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079553/how-to-handle-a-compositecollection-with-collectionview-features)

Comment: Nope. `'MS.Internal.Data.CompositeCollectionView' view does not support filtering.`

Comment: @Poma - Take a look at the sample. Create a CompositeCollection and then use it as the source of a CollectionViewSource (which suopports filters).

Comment: @JonathanPiché no it isn't. `new CollectionViewSource { Source = new CompositeCollection() }.View.CanFilter == false`

Comment: Did you try to use the CollectionViewSource.Filter directly instead of going through ".View"?

Comment: Use BindingListCollectionView's CustomFilter: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/49844e5f-0fc5-4bdd-8506-e1d71124ed08

Comment: @Joe tied code from your example. Got exception `Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.Data.CompositeCollectionView' to type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView'.`