# View Filter not working for a readonly ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, inotifypropertychanged

I have a property :

```
public ObservableCollection<Mapping> Mapping
{
  get { return new ObservableCollection<Mapping>(_standardMappings
                                             .Union(_userDefinedMappings)); }
}
```

that is triggered (`OnPropertyChanged`) when a new item is added/removed to the underlying collections.

I am binding to a `ListView` and everything works except for filtering. I am doing filtering as follows:

```
  var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Mapping);
  view.Filter = filteringPredicate;
```

The filtering code is hit, but the `ListView` never changes its view. I am able to get this to work by doing something like this

```
private ObservableCollection<Mapping> _mappings;
public ObservableCollection<Mapping> Mappings { get{ return _mappings; } }
```

And, on `OnCollectionChanged` of the underlying collections:

```
private void OnMappingCollectionChanged()
{
  _standardMappings.CollectionChanged -= OnMappingCollectionChanged;
  _userDefinedMappings.CollectionChanged -= OnMappingCollectionChanged;
  _buttonMappings.Clear();
  _standardMappings.ToList().ForEach(mapping=>_mappings.Add(mapping));
  _userDefinedMappings.ToList().ForEach(mapping=>_mappings.Add(mapping));
  _standardmMappings.CollectionChanged += OnMappingCollectionChanged;
  _userDefinedMappings.CollectionChanged += OnMappingCollectionChanged;
}
```

However, this is a really crappy solution IMO

And, I did look at `CompositeCollection`, but [you cannot filter on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288/wpf-sorting-a-composite-collection)

Comment: Second code do makes sense. Why you need to return new instance of `ObservableCollection<T>` always?

Comment: @RohitVats Because, if one of the underlying collections change, then that is not reflected in the aggregate mapping

Comment: Are underlying source collections of type `ObservableCollection`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the view to cause re-evaluation of the filter condition.

```
view.Refresh();
```

Comment: That doesnt solve the problem. As I said, the filtering code is hit